# How to create a high speed counter that updates every 40 msec and gets synchronized with a server side method

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web application that controls a professional video player. The player is controlled by a 3rd party dll that is embedded in my asp.net iis running web application. I can control the player but now i also want to have a timer that displays the current position of the clip when playing. The api has a call to fetch the number of frames from the device. I can then convert that integer number to a valid human readable time code display in hours:minutes:seconds:frames So far so good, but i want to have a nice running counter on the webpage without needing to over ask the api.The counter ideally gets updated every 40 msec (1 frame at 25hz has a duration of 40msec) I tried several approaches already like having a timer server side and combining it with signalr to update the html label but it doesn't perform well. My next idea is to use some java script for the actual time code counter. I already obtain at clip load the the initial start time code in frames. Pressing the play button would then set the player and the counter in motion. My idea is then to synchronize it (while running) with time code information returned from a server side method call(ajax). ...sounds ambitious so that is why i ask for some help and advice from the community. Has anybody a good idea how to solve my problem? Thanks

Comment: what is sychronizing with the server for? why is it required to make it so frequent?

Comment: Hi, Well the counter is like i described a video counter. (SMPTE 12M) You are right about the frequency. I suppose it doesn't have to synchronise at every frame  but the time code that is displayed is part of the video clip. So it should have some relevance to the picture. In my previous attempts i simply called the server side method to fetch the time code from the device when ever i stopped or paused the clip. I guess that when the clip is playing the human eye can't really see if the time is actually a few frames off. As long as the seconds are close to sync.

Comment: All things you are doing is about the UI displaying, which should be fully controlled by the front-end application, which is javascript in your pages, so the server application is irrelavent.

Comment: Alsein, can you help me out a bit with some code example? Java script is not my strongest coding language.